# D: Delegates or callbacks?

Tags: callback, delegates, d

I found conception of Delegates pretty hard for me. I really do not understand why I can't simply pass one function to another and need to wrap it to Delegate. I read in docs that there is some cases when I do not know it's name and Delegate is only way to call it.

But now I have trouble in understanding conception of callbacks. I tried to find more information, but I can't understand is it's simply call of other function or what is it.

Could you show examples of D callbacks and explain where they can be helpful?

```
import vibe.d;

shared static this()
{
    auto settings = new HTTPServerSettings;
    settings.port = 8080;

    listenHTTP(settings, &handleRequest);
}

void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest req,
                   HTTPServerResponse res)
{
    if (req.path == "/")
        res.writeBody("Hello, World!", "text/plain");
}
```

`&handleRequest` is it callback? How it's work and at what moment it's start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass functions to other functions to later be called.

```
void test(){}
void receiver(void function() fn){
    // call it like a normal function with 'fn()'
    // or pass it around, save it, or ignore it
}

// main
receiver(&test); // 'test' will be available as 'fn' in 'receiver'
```

You need to prepend the function name as argument with `&` to clarify you want to pass a function pointer. If you don't do that, it will instead call that function due to UFCS (calling without braces). It is not a delegate yet.

The function that receives your callable may do whatever it wants with it. A common example is in your question, a web service callback. First you tell the framework what should be done in case a request is received (by defining actions in a function and making that function available for the framework), and in your example enter a loop with `listenHTTP` which calls your code when it receives a request. If you want to read more on this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)#Event_handler

Delegates are function pointers with context information attached. Say you want to add handlers that act on other elements available in the current context. Like a button that turns an indicator red. Example:

```
class BuildGui {

    Indicator indicator;
    Button button;

    this(){
        ... init
        button.clickHandler({ // curly braces: implicit delegate in this case
            indicator.color = "red"; // notice access of BuildGui member
        });
        button.clickHandler(&otherClickHandler); // methods of instances can be delegates too
    }

    void otherClickHandler(){
        writeln("other click handler");
    }

}
```

In this imaginary `Button` class all click handlers are saved to a list and called when it is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

So within memory a function is just a pile of bytes. Like an array, you can take a pointer to it. This is a function pointer. It has a type of `RETT function(ARGST)` in D. Where RETT is the return type and ARGST are the argument types. Of course attributes can be applied like any function declaration.

Now delegates are a function pointer **with** a context pointer. A context pointer can be anything from a single integer (argument), call frame (function inside of another) or lastly a class/struct.

A delegate is very similar to a function pointer type at `RETT delegate(ARGST)`. They are not interchangeable, but you can turn a function pointer into a delegate pointer pretty easily.

The concept of a callback is to say, hey I know you will know about X so when that happens please tell me about X by calling this function/delegate.

To answer your question about `&handleRequest`, yes it is a callback.

Comment: I'd also add this:
Usually when a function takes a callback as a parameter, the callback type is `delegate`, because that way it can accept both regular functions and delegates. It's trivial to convert a `function` to a `delegate` (as said here), but converting a `delegate` to a `function` would require generating new function code at runtime (which is totally feasible, but not the kind of hack you'd usually want to be dealing with).

Comment: You may want to mention [`toDelegate`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html#toDelegate) to clarify "you can turn a function pointer into a delegate pointer pretty easily". They are easily, but not _implicitly_ convertible.

Answer (score 2):

There were several questions in the OP. I am going to try to answer the following two:

**Q: Could you show examples of D callbacks and explain where they can be helpful?**

**A:** They are commonly used in all languages that support delegates (C# for an example) as event handlers. - You give a delegate to be called whenever an event is triggered. Languages that do not support delegates use either classes, or callback functions for this purpose. Example how to use callbacks in C++ using the [FLTK 2.0 library](http://www.fltk.org): http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/group__example2.html. Delegates are perfect for this as they can directly access the context. When you use callbacks for this purpose you have to pass along all the objects you want to modify in the callback... Check the mentioned FLTK link as an example - there we have to pass a pointer to the `fltk::Window` object to the `window_callback` function in order to manipulate it. (The reason why FLTK does this is that back FLTK was born C++ did not have lambdas, otherwise they would use them instead of callbacks)

Example D use: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_signals.html

**Q: Why I can't simply pass one function to another and need to wrap it to Delegate?**

**A:** You do not have to wrap to delegates - it depends what you want to accomplish... Sometimes passing callbacks will just work for you. You can't access context in which you may want to call the callback, but delegates can. You can, however pass the context along (and that is what some C/C++ libraries do).

I think what you are asking is explained in the [D language reference](http://dlang.org/function.html#closures)

Quote 1:

> A function pointer can point to a static nested function

Quote 2:

> A delegate can be set to a non-static nested function

Take a look at the last example in that section and notice how a delegate can be a method:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a = 7;
    int bar() { return a; }
}

int foo(int delegate() dg)
{
    return dg() + 1;
}

void test()
{
    int x = 27;
    int abc() { return x; }
    Foo f;
    int i;

    i = foo(&abc);   // i is set to 28
    i = foo(&f.bar); // i is set to 8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already excellent answers. I just want to try to make simple summary.

Simply: delegate allows you to use methods as callbacks.

In C, you do the same by explicitly passing the object (many times named context) as void* and cast it to (hopefully) right type:

```
void callback(void *context, ...) {
    /* Do operations with context, which is usually a struct */

    doSomething((struct DATA*)context, ...);
    doSomethingElse((struct DATA*)context, ...);
}
```

In C++, you do the same when wanting to use method as callback. You make a function taking the object pointer explicitly as void*, cast it to (hopefully) right type, and call method:

```
void callback(void* object, ...) {
    ((MyObject*)object)->method(...);
}
```

Delegate makes this all implicitly.